# UIWebView with absolute path reference to CSS

Tags: ios

I have a number of web pages that are used inside a UIWebView that currently reference resources with both relative and absolute paths like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/path/mycss.css"/>
<img src="myimage.png" />
```

The HTML file itself is at path "/page/path/page.html" with myimage.png in the same directory. These same pages are also used for rendering directly in a browser and ideally I'd rather not change the paths. On the iPad, the web site content is dynamically loaded into the Documents directory for offline viewing. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any way to get UIWebView to handle the resolution of the absolute paths. I'm using the following to load the content:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];    
[self loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```

If I point baseURL at the "/page/path" directory, UIWebView will correctly find myimage.png, but will not find mycss.css. I also tried pointing baseURL at the Documents directory, but this fails to resolve either resource. In fact, I haven't been able to get UIWebView to resolve any absolute paths at all.

Has anyone been able to get absolute paths to work with UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use something like that (see below) for the path of your CSS ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/path/mycss.css"/>
<img src="myimage.png" />
```

Comment: that would work, but like I said, I'm trying to avoid changing the pages/paths. There's a content management system involved, bureaucracy, etc. It's a bit surprising to me that UIWebView can't handle this. I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: how would UIWebView know to look for resources in the Documents directory in the baseURL is nil?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want some absolute path references in your html files ?

I don't think it is a good idea, because you cannot know your future users application installation pathes.

For example, my embedded web page is at

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/0E8A7BA5-8DB7-4F88-AC69-0E48F9182DD2/MyApp.app/homepage/index.html
```

The 0E8A7BA5-8DB7-4F88-AC69-0E48F9182DD2 part changes every time you delete your app !

I think the good way is

- adding your website in xCode by selecting "Create folder references for any added folders"
- only have some relative pathes
- use :

  ```
  NSString * urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"homepage"];
  NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString isDirectory:NO];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)10.0 ];
  ```

Comment: your html is embedded in your app bundle and I assume under your control. My html is dynamically delivered via a custom sync process over http and stored in the Documents directory. The pages are built by another group using a CMS and those same pages used to deliver a non-mobile web site. It isn't unusual in that scenario to have absolute paths. I have to weigh the politics of asking that group to make all references relative.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Unfortunately, because of the unknow part of the application folder, you can't use absolute pathes. I think the best solution for you is to pre-process your files (with perl for example, or directly in the mobile app) and transform each absolute url with a relative one (witch base folder is your website root directory)